# PostgreSQL - GROUP_BY issue with common table expression (CTE)

Tags: group-by, postgis, psql

The below query to attain the count of shops (table SHOPS) within the shapefile of a city and all adjacent cities throws this error; shapefiles are in table GEO:

```
GroupingError: column "GEO.city_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

My codes include `CityAndAdjacent.city_name` and I tried it with `GEO.city_name`. Same error for both. I also tried to `MAX(CityAndAdjacent.city_name) AS city_name` in the `SELECT` statement after the CTE. None of these adjustments worked. I appreciate any pointers.

```sql
WITH CityAndAdjacent AS (
  SELECT
    city_name,
    ST_Union(geom) AS city_and_adjacent_geom
  FROM
    GEO
  WHERE
    city_name = 'City name'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    GEO.city_name,
    GEO.geom
  FROM
    GEO
  INNER JOIN
    CityAndAdjacent
  ON
    ST_Intersects(GEO.geom, CityAndAdjacent.city_and_adjacent_geom)
)
SELECT
  CityAndAdjacent.city_name,
  COUNT(SHOPS.*) AS shop_count
FROM
  CityAndAdjacent
LEFT JOIN
  SHOPS
ON
  ST_Within(SHOPS.geom, CityAndAdjacent.city_and_adjacent_geom)
GROUP BY
  CityAndAdjacent.city_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your recursive query, you are `st_union`ing all polygons of a city, but the name is not aggregated. You can try, among other possibilities:

```sql
SELECT
    city_name,
    ST_Union(geom) AS city_and_adjacent_geom
  FROM
    GEO 
  WHERE
    city_name = 'City name'
  GROUP BY city_name
...
```

On a side note, your query would be much more efficient if you your identify the polygon IDs and then join the points to the individual identified polygons. Doing so would allow using the spatial index.

Comment: Thanks JGH. Unfortunately, adding another GROUP_BY did not do the trick.

Comment: @raummensch could elaborate on how this query might not work? Perhaps adding the error message or the unexpected result set? It looks just fine to me